# data integrity issue with ntfs but not ext3

Tags: linux, caching, filesystems, ntfs, ext3

In my application I am continually writing data to **file1** and flushing it to the device. In another thread, I am reading data from **file1** and writing it to **file2**.

Every time I do the **fwrite + fflush** on file1, I signal to the other thread to start reading from it. The other thread reads data from file1 and dumps it into file2. Pretty simple logic. Additionally, after every few minutes, I seek back to start of file1 and start overwriting old data.

Now my problem is that once I start overwriting data in **file1**, the data read into file2 is **sometimes** the old data (i.e. data written in the previous iteration) even though writer thread has signaled that it wrote the new data (and flushed it).

I am writing to and reading from a solid state drive (128 GB SAMSUNG 470 Series, if that helps) on [C + linux + arm platfrom]. I feel that there is an issue with the processor cache. Perhaps the **write** goes into the cache and the **read** by the reader thread comes from the flash, and hence the stale data.

The catch here is that this problem occurs if the SSD is formatted with NTFS. If I format it with ext3, the problem goes away. Unfortunately, NTFS is a hard requirement. Another interesting observation is that if I have two reader threads, both get stale data at different instants.

Event after disabling the SSD write cache (with **hdparm -W0 /dev/sda1**), I get the same problem with NTFS. I am badly stuck up with this since more than a week.

Any idea what is happening, and why is it happening that way?

Any help will be worth its weight in gold...

**EDIT** Turns out that the NTFS driver does not like me overwriting a file by rewinding the file pointer. Is this a known thing?

Comment: did you try to reopen file in thread one with overwrite mode? Also, How do you read data from file1 in thread 2, did you reopen the file?

Comment: Are you using ntfs-3g or the in-kernel ntfs driver?

Comment: @Asad: No, I do not reopen the file, I just do rewind(fp). I'll try your suggestion.  @Bdonlan: I use tuxera embedded ntfs driver (commercial)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Tuxera driver, but this sounds like a bug the particular implementation of NTFS that you're using. The SSD issue is something of a hint. We'd be looking very closely at this if this was in the Microsoft NTFS driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue myself (and how rarely does that happen !!!).

I found that there was a problem with the C library buffering (fread/fwrite). So I do fflush() before every fread(). This solves my problem (I don't know what exactly went wrong with the driver but I am assuming that there is some issue with the "read" buffering of the C library I/O functions, when reading from the same location of the file second time around).

Thanks @Asad Rasheed and @jrtipton for your inputs :)